# Sitecore Rich Text Editor/ HTML Editor throwing parsing error

Tags: sitecore-client

I have a requirement to show the tool tip to user for allowed special character on registration page, so i have created a template and adding the following content `"<li>Allowed special character are " ! # $ % & ’ ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [ ] ^ _` { | } ~"` to using Rich Text Editor, but Rich Text Editor is not allowing this content. Please let me know how to achieve this through sitecore content editor.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you HTML encode the text? There a free online websites which do this.

Comment: Hi Michael, i tried using the encoding the characters, but still the same result. 
<li>Allowed special character are &quot; ! # $ % &amp; &rsquo; ( ) * + , - . / : ; &lt; = &gt; ? @ [ ] ^ _ ` { | } ~</li>

Comment: Which version of Sitecore are you using? I tried your html with special characters in Sitecore 8.1 and 9.0.2 and it works. Do you have any additional validation rules applied? Maybe your html is not valid.

Comment: try this - `<li>Allowed special character are " ! # $ % &amp; &rsquo; ( ) * + , - . / : ; &lt; =="" /&gt; ? @ [ ] ^ _ { | } ~</li>`